# Parsing regular expression from API return

Tags: java, android, regex, string, string-parsing

I would like to seek help on how to parse this string

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":500,"message":"No keyword found."}}
```

I would want to be able to get the error code and the error message. The only problem I have is finding a regex that could capture the values I'm stuck at

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX?);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
```

Comment: That looks a lot like JSON. Could you parse it as such?

Comment: Why you do not use a json parser?

Comment: this look like json string, you should parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse it to json and get value not regex as your response is in JSON.

```
JSONObject message = new JSONObject(yourResponse);
// use myJson as needed, for example 
JSONObject error = message.getJSONObject(“error”);
int code = error.getInt(“code”);
String message2 = error.getString(“message”);
```

Comment: Hmm, casting Strign to an int?

Comment: you can see, code is returned as int And Its in JSON Format.

Comment: ya that was my mistake. sorry.

Comment: It is your comment that was the mistake.  Why are programmers so defensive?

Comment: Hi I tried it but it gives me `05-22 14:28:19.847: W/System.err(13787): org.json.JSONException: Value Internal of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` on the line `JSONObject message = new JSONObject(status.message);`

Comment: This code working I tried just copy :: JSONObject message = new JSONObject("{\"success\":false,\"error\":{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"No keyword found.\"}}");
// use myJson as needed, for example
            JSONObject error = message.getJSONObject("error");
            int code = error.getInt("code");
            String message2 = error.getString("message");
            Log.d("bis", "code "+code);

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we do not often compile Patterns for such trivial tasks.

**Quick Answer**

```
code = Integer.parseInt(result.split("\"")[6].split(",")[0].substring(1));
msg = result.split("\"")[9].split(",")[0];
```

This won't work if `result` has commas.

Answer (score 0):

if you want regex, this is it

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*\"code\":(.+?),.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library is easy to use. Example code is as below:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
int errCode= obj.getJSONObject("error").getInt("code");
```

Answer (score 0):

This string is in json format, better use a json parser. Try this:

```
String s = "{\"success\":false,\"error\":{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"No keyword found.\"}}";
JSONObject jsonObject;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject error = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("error");
    System.out.println(error.get("message"));
    System.out.println(error.get("code"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also have a look at [this site](http://regular-expressions.info/).